# Is it possible to use multiple lines in Angular attributes?

Tags: angularjs

Is is possible to include a newline in an Angular JS expression in an attribute tag? Something like this:

```
<p ng-repeat="
    foo in foos 
    | filter:{attr: 'something really long'} 
    | orderBy:bar">
  {{foo}}
</p>
```

EDIT: To clarify, the above doesn't work. I was wondering if there is some other syntax that allows for breaking this kind of expressions into multiple lines.

Comment: What happens if you try it?

Comment: It should work. New line (any white space) does not matter as long as you maintain syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

angular.js parser would be able to handle it, but there's a quick regex check before handing it to the parser (see http://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat:iexp):

> Be aware, the ngRepeat directive parses the expression using a regex
>   before sending collection and optionally id to the AngularJS parser.
>   This error comes from the regex parsing.

I filed a bug to loosen this restriction: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5537, you can hand-patch it in the meantime, it's just 1 character: `m` (`/regex/m`).

Comment: Looks like a partial fix will be included in some 1.2.x version (milestone is set), github says 1.2.7 is due in the new year, though not sure if it will be included.

Comment: Bug opened by me is fixed, it'll in some next release.

Comment: I am currently using Angular version 1.5.8 and looks like spanning ng-repeat over multiple lines is still not working. Can anyone please confirm this?

Comment: @valafar according to https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/c9705b755645a4bfe066243f2ba15a733c3787e1 the fix should be included in that version.

Comment: Ah, it works. Was a stupid mistake from my end. Thanks for the quick answer and for reporting the bug. :)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible for an expressions to span multiple lines. But ng-repeat throws an error if you try to span the expression on multiple lines.

Take a look at this plunker:
Add a new line in the ng-repeat expression and open the browser console to see the error message.

http://plnkr.co/edit/E1O8Iy3VzL3kzj72BDUL?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to use multiline attributes with ANY HTML element, including AngularJS directives.

Comment: Sure, no one will prohibit you from doing so, but the Angular code will not recognize it.